# JQuery mobile Map doesn't show

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

Something is wrong with my google map code.

```js
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.5968, 22.9683); //Google map Coordinates
var map;

map_initialize(); // initialize google map

//############### Google Map Initialize ##############
function map_initialize() {
  var googleMapOptions = {
    center: mapCenter, // map center
    zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 12,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
    },
    scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="google_map"></div>
```

Comment: removed extraneous text

Answer (score 0):

I assume you included Google Maps Javascript API with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
```

Here is where you are wrong:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                                                    ^^^^
```

You didn't define a function with name `initialize`, change it to `map_initialize` and remove the independent call of that function at the beginning.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);
```

This line will try to initialize your map by calling `map_initialize()` after the load of page.

You should refer to the official documentation for more information:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/